# How to change merge result to list and use openpyxl write into column?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl

1. I have two different excel to compare...

   ```
        Data1.xlsx                                     Data2.xlsx
   |  Name   |  Reg Date  |    |  Name   |   City    |  Reg Date  | Gender | Data1.xlsx |
   |Annie    | 2021-07-01 |    |Alex     | Hong Kong | 2021-07-04 | Male   |            |
   |Billy    | 2021-07-02 |    |Annie    | Hong Kong | 2021-07-01 | Female |            |
   |Cathrine | 2021-07-03 |    |Bob      | Taipei    | 2021-07-02 | Male   |            |
   |David    | 2021-07-04 |    |Lucy     | Tokyo     | 2021-07-01 | Female |            |
   |Eric     | 2021-07-04 |    |David    | London    | 2021-07-04 | Male   |            |
                               |Kate     | New York  | 2021-07-03 | Female |            |
                               |Cathrine | London    | 2021-07-03 | Female |            |
                               |Rose     | Hong Kong | 2021-07-04 | Female |            |
   ```
2. I get `Name` & `Reg Date` for key to merge and `iloc` for `Data1.xlsx`

   ```
   import openpyxl as xl
   import pandas as pd
   dt1 = pd.read_excel('Data1.xlsx')
   dt2 = pd.read_excel('Data2.xlsx')
   df_merge = pd.merge(dt2, dt1[['Name', 'Reg Date']], on=['Name', 'Reg Date'], how='left', indicator=True)
   df_merge['Data1.xlsx'] = np.where(df_merge.pop('_merge').eq('both'), 'Y', 'N')

      Name      City       Reg Date    Gender  Data1.xlsx 
   0  Alex      Hong Kong  2021-07-04  Male    N            
   1  Annie     Hong Kong  2021-07-01  Female  Y           
   2  Bob       Taipei     2021-07-02  Male    N           
   3  Lucy      Tokyo      2021-07-01  Female  N           
   4  David     London     2021-07-04  Male    Y           
   5  Kate      New York   2021-07-03  Female  N           
   6  Cathrine  London     2021-07-03  Female  Y           
   7  Rose      Hong Kong  2021-07-04  Female  N

   merge_loc = df_merge.iloc[:, [4]]

      Data1.xlsx 
   0  N            
   1  Y           
   2  N           
   3  N           
   4  Y           
   5  N           
   6  Y           
   7  N
   ```
3. I use `openpyxl` read `Data2.xlsx` excel file

   ```
   wb = xl.Workbook('Data2.xlsx')
   ws = wb.active
   ```
4. I want to ask how to change `merge_loc` to list with hidden index and use `openpyxl` write list into column `E` of `Data2.xlsx`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to loop over the array to write the values:

```
# compute the data
to_write = np.where(df_merge['_merge'].eq('both'), 'Y', 'N')
# array(['N', 'Y', 'N', 'N', 'Y', 'N', 'Y', 'N'], dtype='<U1')

# write the data
import openpyxl as xl

wb = xl.load_workbook('Data2.xlsx')
ws = wb.active

for row, value in enumerate(to_write, start=2):
    ws[f'E{row}'].value = value

wb.save('Data2.xlsx')
```